# Font issue on using lualatex with beamer

Tags: fonts, beamer, luatex

I am trying to use `beamer` with `lualatex` to produce a presentation (MacTex 2011). Somehow, it doesn't seem to honor the font settings. See the sample below, is there anything I am missing here?

```
\documentclass[lualatex]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Helvetica}

\title{Something to do}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{I am impressed}
Text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79420/changing-font-style-using-beamer/79423. The solution there still allows you to use a sans font by the normal means.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`beamer` switches by default to the sans serif font, the reason why you have to use also

```
\setsansfont{Helvetica}
```