# Changing font style using beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I want to change font style in my presentation. I prefere Liberation Serif font. This is TrueType font so XeLaTeX can be used. I tried to set this font using `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}`, but the font in my document isn't changed. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

By default, `beamer` uses sans serif font, so `\setmainfont` will do nothing. You have to tell it that you want serif fonts:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Abdce
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a similar problem as @Pavel Morozkin, I tried this code and I get the following error: 
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"!! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.!! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or! "lualatex"instead of "latex" or "pdflatex".!! See the fontspec documentation for further information.!! For immediate help type H <return>.!............................................... \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}

Comment: I am also getting a similar error.

Comment: @Peaceful You need to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Gunelle I suppose if you're using Overleaf, there's not a lot you can do.

Answer (score 1):

Beamer uses sans serif font by default, so you can use `\setsansfont{...}` to change the font (even if the font you actually want to use has serifs...)

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to modify the directive to incorporate `latexmk` functionality?

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 Did you try `latexmk -lulatex`?

Comment: That works! Thank you.

Comment: But is there also a directive `% TEX TS-program = ...` to do the same thing?

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 On unix based systems, the following can be used: `% !TeX TS-program = latexmk -lualatex %` (don't know if this will also work on MS)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. What editor are you using? I'm using TeXShop. (Also, in TeXShop, I find that I need to capitalize `!TeX` as `!TEX`.)

Comment: @xFioraMstr18 The above command is for texstudio. You should better ask a proper question to get the attention of texshop users.

Comment: I just made a post: [TeXShop directive for LuaLaTeX and latexmk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/691147/112411)