# Incompatibility between Beamer and STIX 2 Font

Tags: beamer

After compiling this code with the lualatex-engine, the approx-symbol isn't printed. I can't understand why. Somebody can help me please ?

```
\documentclass[lualatex, utf8]{beamer}

\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[ Re \approx 10^8 \]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated:  AFAIK `fontenc` should not be used with xelatex or lulatex

Comment: with the fontspec package or without it, the matter is the same

Answer (score 5):

### With Modern Fonts

If you’re running LuaLaTeX, you can use `unicode-math`.  This supports Unicode and all TrueType and OpenType fonts, and wipes out a lot of the technical debt LaTeX owes to the 1980s.  For example, fonts needing to pack all their math symbols into a limited number of 256-character math alphabets and doing that in different ways.  I personally recommend that you use the modern tools whenever you can, and the legacy fonts whenever you have to.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[ Re \approx 10^8 \]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: OpenType font sample]

I also removed some package options that you no longer need.  (LaTeX 3 already makes UTF-8 the default input encoding, and the class can detect which engine it’s running on.)

You can change the text font to whatever you please, or define a separate `\setsansfont`.  See the documentation of `fontspec` if you want the details.

It’s also possible to use a font of your choice for variable names in math mode, along with the symbols from your math font, with the `range=` option of `\setmathfont`.  See the documentation of `unicode-math` for the details.

### With Legacy 8-Bit Fonts

The problem here was that `beamer` tries to substitute some of the fonts in the document.  If you run `pdffonts` on the PDF file you get, you’ll see that it’s trying to use `LMSans` (Latin Modern Sans) instead of STIX Two.  The class detects certain font packages, as well as `unicode-math`, and changes its behavior to be compatible with them. However, `stix2` is not one of those packages (as of 2020).

You therefore need to turn these substitutions off with `professionalfonts`:

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[ Re \approx 10^8 \]
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Type1 font sample]

You can load whatever other fonts you want after `stix2`.  If you want to stick to sans-serif fonts as the default, for example, you can `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}` or load a font package with a `[sfdefault]` option.

Comment: I ran the code, but my normal text is not in the STIX2 font (even though I have run `\setmainfont[Scale=1.0]{STIX Two Text}` and I am running LuaLaTeX on the latest MikTeX distribution. I have a MWE [here](https://www.overleaf.com/7242271919ykrdqbbfqjgr). Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SudipSinha It would be better to post this as a question on this site. The comment system is not really designed for that.

Comment: Thanks @davislor; I'll keep it in mind for the future.

I just figured out the solution to my question. I had to use `\usefonttheme{serif}`. The details are in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79423/16796). I'll keep this here in case anyone has the same issue.

Comment: @SudipSinha `professionalfonts`, like in my answer, should work as well. I had thought that a Beamer doc using `unicode-math` shouldn’t need iit.