# Beamer doesn't render "(", "-" and "/"

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, equations, stix

When I render this code on overleaf:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\DJ{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\char208}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{some text}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $ \mu_0 M = \chi_p\left(B_a + B_E \right)$
    \item  $\chi_p= C / T$
    \item lalalaal:
            \begin{equation}
                \chi = \frac{M}{B_a} = \frac{C}{T-C\lambda}.
            \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get (note missing ")" in first equation, missing "/" in second and missing "-" in third):

[image: Render]

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This appears to be realted to the `stix2` package. At least, the equations are shown as expected if I comment out the before mentioned package.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525220/134144 seems to be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the screenshot you posted, the fact that the math font is *not* a Times Roman clone should be a dead give-away that the `stix2` package wasn't loaded properly. You need to provide the instruction `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` before running `\usepackage{stix2}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
}

\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{xurl} 
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\DJ{{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\char208}}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{stix2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{some text}
\begin{itemize}
    \item $\mu_0 M = \chi_p(B_a + B_E )$
    \item $\chi_p= C / T$
    \item lalalaal:
            \begin{equation}
                \chi = \frac{M}{B_a} = \frac{C}{T-C\lambda}.
            \end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In case you're wondering what `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` does and/or why it's needed, here's an excerpt from pp. 196 f. of the `beamer` user guide:

[image]
[image]

Note the final instruction. Do contact the package's maintainer(s) and ask them to add `stix2` to the list of font packages which automatically prompt `beamer` to execute `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`.