# TeXShop directive for LuaLaTeX and latexmk

Tags: luatex, texshop, latexmk

Is there a TeXShop directive (something like `% !TEX TS-program = lualatex`) that I can place at the top of my document and can tell TeXShop to compile using LuaLaTeX with `latexmk`?

That is, a TeXShop directive that does the equivalent of `latexmk -lualatex file.tex`.

Comment: Note: this question grew out of my attempt to implement in TeXShop samcarter's [solution to a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652224/112411).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your TeXShop Engines folder contains `pdflatexmk`, `lualatexmk` and `xelatexmk` engines. (They may be in the Inactive folder, in which case simply move them to the main Engines folder and restart TeXShop.) Then you can simply use:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
```

Comment: In TeXShop, the `e` in `!TeX` needs to be capitalized. Your answer works, provided that I make that adjustment.

Comment: Also, I wonder why I didn't think of this solution myself—I had previously used `pdflatexmk`, which I had set up using the same method (I think).

Comment: `% !TEX program = lualatexmk` has always worked for me without the `TS`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL If it works, then no. :) But if you use the Macros -> Program menu item to insert the relevant engine, it will add the line with the TS, so that's what I've always used.

Comment: Interesting. I've never used the Macros menu for anything.

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL It has some useful stuff, including one I wrote :). Don't you have any macros of your own?

Comment: @AlanMunn I experimented with command completions, but never macros. Perhaps I should.